# Android Asynctask : The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-asynctask

My code works but I have this abnormal message in the Monitor : I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I understand this error message means I'm doing to much heavy treatment in the UI thread. The thing is that for me I do nearly nothing on the UI thread except adding fake data to a ListView. I'm using an AsyncTask to make an API request and this is the only "heavy" work i'm doing,and it's not in the main thread.

I put all my code down here but I think most part of it is not the problem because I still have this issue when i comment all my fake data code and the call to my AsyncTask. So I guess the problem is more about how I use this Fragment because I never used one so I surely made a mistake anywhere with it...

```
//==== list_item_forecast.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview" />

//====fragment_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- using a FrameLayout because only one child element -->
<FrameLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"/>
</FrameLayout>

//==== content_main.xml
<fragment     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />


//==== MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ForecastRequest {

    private static String appId = "";
    // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
    String forecastJsonStr = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Get OpenWeather API key
        appId = getResources().getString(R.string.APPID);

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast     API page, at
        // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            String url =     "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?    q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&APPID=" + appId;
            OpenWeatherRequest request = new OpenWeatherRequest();
            request.response = this;
            request.execute(url);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void requestDone(String jsonResponse) {
        forecastJsonStr = jsonResponse;
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG,forecastJsonStr);
    }
}

//==== Interface used to get result from AsyncTask in MainActivity
public interface ForecastRequest {
    void requestDone(String output);
}

//==== The AsyncTask that make a request to OpenWeather API
public class OpenWeatherRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
    // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
    String forecastJsonStr = null;
    public ForecastRequest response = null;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG,"Fetching data...");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream =     urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new Exception("No data");
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return forecastJsonStr;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        response.requestDone(result);
    }
}

//==== The fragment
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> weekForecast;
    private ListView mListView;


    public MainActivityFragment() {

    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup     container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,     container, false);

        //=== Add fake data
        weekForecast = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                "Weds - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Thurs - Asteroids - 75/65",
                "Fri - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
                "Sat - HELP TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 60/51",
                "Sun - Sunny - 80/68")
        );

        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                // The current context (this fragment parent activity)
                getActivity(),
                // ID of list item layout
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                // ID of the textview to populate
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                // Data
                weekForecast);

        mListView =     (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        mListView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I get my data but have this abnormal message : I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: I think it's happening when you open the Activity itself, not when running AsyncTask. Have you tried not to start AsyncTask and see if you still get the message? I bet you will see it. Also I don't see why would you want to catch an Exception on execute(). There is nothing you should really catch there.

Comment: I answered my own question, emulator problem... anyway thank you for your comment about execute(), useless, as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried on my phone and not on the Android Studio emulator and the message disappeared. So the problem came from the emulator and not from my code.